# one to many association is getting stack over flow error in groovy with grails.Please Check below classes, logs if there are any association errors

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

one to many association is getting stack over flow error in groovy with grails. Please Check below classes, error log to see if there are any association.
errors.

This is what I tried so far:

Earlier association is from B to C class, now we modified it A to B class after making this association changes. Changes looks good to me but while accessing b's from A class its throwing stackoverflow error getBs method from A.groovy. If I remove getBs method its giving null as B even though b's available for that contract in db. Also calling B.findAllByContract dynamic finder method its throwing could not resolve property 'a' even though its available at class level. Could you please guide me here

```
class A implements Serializable {
    static stampable = true
    static auditable = true
    static hasMany = [
        bs: B]
    static mapping = {
        bs joinTable: [column: "a_id"]
    }
    static mappedBy = [ bs: "a"]
    def getBs() {
        println "calling ..."
        return bs
    }
}
class B implements Serializable { 
    A a
    static constraints = {
        a nullable:true
    }
    static mapping = {
        sort title: "asc"
        a column: "a_id"
    }
    static transients = ['BValue']
}
```

error log:

```
2021-03-28 13:06:10,825 {yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} admin ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/app].[grailsDispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [grailsDispatcherServlet] in context with path [/app] threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError] with root cause
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.format(InvokerHelper.java:583)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.format(InvokerHelper.java:575)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.toString(InvokerHelper.java:130)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.println(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:642)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$504.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:251)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:59)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:166)
        at app.A.getBs(A.groovy:245)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor878.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1426)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:1852)
        at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.getProperty(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1155)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:3735)
        at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.getProperty(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1167)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassGetPropertySite.getProperty(PogoMetaClassGetPropertySite.java:51)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGroovyObjectGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:307)
        at app.A.getBs(A.groovy:246)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor878.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1426)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:1852)
        at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.getProperty(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1155)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:3735)
        at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.getProperty(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1167)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassGetPropertySite.getProperty(PogoMetaClassGetPropertySite.java:51)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGroovyObjectGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:307)
        at app.A.getBs(A.groovy:246)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor878.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

Comment: Please add the complete stacktrace - it shows the methods that are calling each other.

Comment: Sure, updated with full stack trace and explained what I did so far.

Comment: Remove `getBs`, or rename it

Comment: thank you it works now, it worked for me only when I ran command 'grails clean' as well after removing this method.

Answer (score 1):

Try updating the method getBs as follows:

```
def getBs() {
    println "calling ..."
    return this.bs
}
```

I think referring `bs` might be recursively calling `getBs()`.